# Using jquery tagit plugin, Is there anyway to disable all entry?

Tags: jquery, tag-it, disabled-control

I have a page and i am using [jquery tagit plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) which works great but i am trying to disable it when i click on a button, and have it have similar behavior to when i disable a select Dropdown like this:

```
 $("#selectDropdown").val(0);
 $('#selectDropdown').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Is there anyway to disable and enable the jquery tagit Plugin programatically.  I see there is a readonly option [on the docs page](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown)  so I tried doing something like this:

```
 $("#locationTags").tagit({ "readOnly": false });
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, can I get some feedback on some of my answers?  Is this what you want?  If it's missing something please let me know so I can address it.  Also you have a bounty ending in a few hours and I haven't got any feedback on my answer for it.  Do you just not like to award your bounties or something?

Comment: I am unable to test answers at work (jsfiddle is blocked) so unfortunately can't award bounties right away sometimes :(

Comment: No problem, thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following demonstrates how you could disable/enable a `tagit` field.

**Updated with David's optimized code.**

```
    $('#disable').click(function(){
        $('.ui-autocomplete-input').prop('disabled', true).val('');
        $('.tagit-choice').remove();
        $('.ui-widget-content').css('opacity','.2'); 
    });
    $('#enable').click(function(){
        $('.ui-widget-content').css('opacity','1');
        $('.ui-autocomplete-input').prop('disabled', false);    
    });
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j8Eg4/1/

Because you want the field to look like a disabled dropdown I opted for this solution.  Another solution that `tagit` supports is if you want to stop tags from being added you can utilize the `beforeTagAdded (function, Callback)` function.  And return false in order to stop new tags from being created...

Here is an example of that.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8Eg4/2/

Comment: Why do you select `.ui-autocomplete-input` twice, [rather than simply chaining](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j8Eg4/1/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas good call that is better.  Chaining is not something I do very often I need to start using or implementing it in my code.  Thanks

Comment: And, just because I had a moment, you can also combine the `disable` and `enable` click-handler into one (with a bit of 'cheating'): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j8Eg4/3/). It does become a little, um, silly though; this sort of approach can definitely be taken too far... :D

Comment: @DavidThomas, wow that code is complex.  Very cool though.  Thanks, i'll be happy to study it!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation enclosing the readOnly.

This should work:

```
$("#locationTags").tagit({ readOnly: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way

**- To disabled**

```
 $("#yourtag").tagit({ readOnly: true });
 $(".tagit-close").find(".text-icon").html("");
```

**- To enabled**

```
 $("#yourtag").tagit({ readOnly: false });
 $(".tagit-close").find(".text-icon").html("×");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make Tag-it entirely Read only. It's in this collection of examples:

http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

The JS source code that does it is as simple as can be:

```
// Read-only
$('#MyTagID').tagit({
    readOnly: true
});
```